# c# DateTime only need date

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
//my model/////////////////////////
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Need a date of birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }


/////my controller//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[HttpGet]
[Route("participantDetails/{ParticipantId}")]
public IActionResult ParticipantDetails(int participantId)
{
        if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        Participant TheParticipant = db.Participants.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == participantId);
        ViewBag.ChildDetailsFirstName = TheParticipant.ParticipantFirstName;
        ViewBag.ChildDetailsLastName = TheParticipant.ParticipantLastName;
        ViewBag.ChildDetailsGender = TheParticipant.ParticipantGender;
        ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB = TheParticipant.ParticipantDOB.Date;
        return View("ParticipantDetailsPage", TheParticipant);
    }


// my cshtml////////////////////////////////////
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
@model Participant
<p>participant details page</p>
<h1>@ViewBag.ChildDetailsFirstName @ViewBag.ChildDetailsLastName</h1>
<p>Gender: @ViewBag.ChildDetailsGender</p>
<p>Date of birth: @ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB</p>
//test////
<p>@Model.ParticipantDOB.Date</p>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i tried looking at microsofts doc and they told me to just add .Date and it still doesn't work. The time stamp is still following my date even though my form never asked for a date

Docs i was looking at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-5.0

Comment: `.Date` will truncate the time and give you a `DateTime` with the time set to midnight (00:00:00).  I think what you want is to format the `DateTime` to only display the date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your date for string output:

```
<p>Date of birth: @ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB</p>
```

Can be something like:

```
<p>Date of birth: @ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB.ToString("d")</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Date of birth: @Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</p>
```

Or just format on your controller before send to view

```
ViewBag.ChildDetailsDOB = TheParticipant.ParticipantDOB.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

using this option there is no need to do .Date

Comment: Though I'd recommend not to do it in the controller, as it throws away info that might be useful elsewhere on the page and converts the data to a format that is harder to work with (string vs date)

Comment: @CaiusJard in that case, create a VM cause ViewBag is dynamic and do not understand about data types (it must be casted). Also the DB Model has the attribute [DataType(DataType.Date)] so in fact there is no more data (time will be append as 0)